# when I used fs.appendFileSync to record data in CSV File it has led to refrech my web page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, csv, socket.io

I am trying to send Data from HTML Page to my Node.js Server via socket.io and then from my Server to Ardouino, Anyway now my goal is to record these Data in a CSV File. For exemple I have created a Map with Leaflet js  and when I move the marker it show up the elevation value based on the position of the marker in the map and now my goal is to record the elevation values every time the marker change his position in the Map, thats why I try it to use  `fs.appendFileSync` and I am already recieving Data in CSV File but the problem is the web page keep refreching every Time I try  to move the Marker. Even when I try it to move the slider in my HTML Page it keep also refreching.
this Problem occuried only when I added the code for recording Data in my Server.

here is my Server Code:

```
const { convertArrayToCSV } = require('convert-array-to-csv');
const fs = require('fs');
var index = fs.readFileSync( 'index.html');
var http = require('http');
var dataArrays=[];

const header = ['value','Time'];
var app = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(index);
});

const io = require('socket.io')(app, {
    cors: {
     origin:"*"
     }
   });

   io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    
    socket.on('servoposition',function(data){
        
        console.log(data.status);
             //here my Data that I want to record:elevation value and Time
            dataArrays = [
            [ data.status,new Date().toString()]
            ];
          
          const csvFromArrayOfArrays = convertArrayToCSV(dataArrays, {
            header,
            separator: ','
          });
            fs.appendFileSync('ouput.csv', csvFromArrayOfArrays, err =>{
            if(err){
                console.log(18, err);
            }


            console.log('CSV File saved successfully');
            })

            
          });
          

    socket.on('motor_elevation',function(data){
        
        console.log( data );
        
        port.write( data.status );
    
    });

    socket.on('servoposition_elevation',function(data){
        
        //port.write( data.status );
        dataArrays = [
            [ data.status,new Date().toString()]
            ];
          
          const csvFromArrayOfArrays = convertArrayToCSV(dataArrays, {
            header,
            separator: ','
          });
            fs.appendFileSync('ouput.csv', csvFromArrayOfArrays, err =>{
            if(err){
                console.log(18, err);
            }


            console.log('CSV File saved successfully');
            })
    
    });
    
});

app.listen(5501,"localhost");
```

I Followed this Link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-array-to-csv to convert-array-to-csv and then I adjust it and I used `fs.appendFileSync`

here is my HTML Page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <title>Communicating from Node.js to an Arduino</title>
        
        
       <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/4.6.1/socket.io.js" integrity="sha512-xbQU0+iHqhVt7VIXi6vBJKPh3IQBF5B84sSHdjKiSccyX/1ZI7Vnkt2/8y8uruj63/DVmCxfUNohPNruthTEQA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
       <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha256-p4NxAoJBhIIN+hmNHrzRCf9tD/miZyoHS5obTRR9BMY=" crossorigin="" />
       <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha256-20nQCchB9co0qIjJZRGuk2/Z9VM+kNiyxNV1lvTlZBo=" crossorigin=""></script> 
       <script type="text/javascript" src="/haptics.js"></script>
       <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/Leaflet.fullscreen.min.js'></script>
       <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-fullscreen/v1.0.1/leaflet.fullscreen.css' rel='stylesheet' />

       <style>
        .slidecontainer {
          width: 50%;
          padding-left: 200px;
        }
        
        .slider {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          width: 50%;
          position: fixed;
          height: 25px;
          background: #d3d3d3;
          outline: none;
          opacity: 0.7;
          -webkit-transition: .2s;
          transition: opacity .2s;
        }
        
        .slider:hover {
          opacity: 1;
        }
        
        .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
          -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
          width: 25px;
          height: 25px;
          background: #04AA6D;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        
        .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
          width: 25px;
          height: 25px;
          background: #04AA6D;
          cursor: pointer;
        }
        /* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
 #infoPanel {
  /*float: right;
  margin-left: 10px;*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
  #map {
    height:50%;
    width:100%;
    float: left;
    top: 113px;
  /*width: 1200px;
  height: 1000px;
  float: left;*/
  }
  
  /* 
   * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
   */
  html,
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    touch-action: none;
  }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

       
        <div class="slidecontainer">
        <input type="range" min="52" max="1275" value="1" class="slider" id="myRange">
        <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
        </div>
        <div id="map"></div>  
        <div id="infoPanel">
          <b>elevation value:</b>
          <div id="markerelevationvalue"><i>drag the marker to see the elevation value.</i></div>
          <b>User hint:</b>
          <div id="info"></div>
          
        </div>

        <script>
            
        var socket = io("ws://localhost:5501");

        const value = "Hello, server!";
        socket.emit("message", value);

        var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
        var output = document.getElementById("demo");


        output.innerHTML = slider.value;
        

        slider.oninput = function() {
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
        
        var slidervalue=parseInt(output.innerHTML);
        var slidertoservo=maprange(slidervalue,52,1275,0,180);
        
        socket.emit('servoposition', { "status":slidertoservo.toString() });
        }
        

        var map = L.map('map').setView([51.55, 9.99], 6);

        L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(map);

        map.addControl(new L.Control.Fullscreen());

        var marker=L.marker([53.556130, 9.99818],{draggable:true}).bindPopup();
        //var poppup=marker.bindPopup('position is'+marker.getLatLng()).openPopup();
        marker.addTo(map);
        var circle1 = L.circle([53.556130, 9.99818], {
        color: 'red',
        fillColor: '#f03',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 6000
        }).addTo(map);

        var circle2 = L.circle([47.3982, 11.11831], {
        color: 'blue',
        fillColor: '#5f1ee3',
        fillOpacity: 0.5,
        radius: 6000
        }).addTo(map);
        marker.addTo(map);


        marker.on('drag', getElevation);
                  
        function getElevation(){
          var latlng = marker.getLatLng();
       
        const api_url='http://localhost:5000/v1/test-dataset?locations='+latlng.lat+','+latlng.lng;
        
        const response= fetch(api_url).then(response => response.json()).then((data)=>{document.getElementById('markerelevationvalue').innerHTML = data.results[0].elevation;
        
        if(data.results[0].elevation>=0){
      
                
            var servominouput= maprange(parseInt(slider.value),52,1275,0,180);
            
            var minoutput=parseInt(servominouput);  
            
            
            var servodegree=maprange(data.results[0].elevation,52,1275,minoutput,180);
            servodegree=parseInt(servodegree);    
             
            socket.emit('servoposition_elevation', { "status":servodegree.toString() });
        } else{}
        
        });
        
         
        }

        function maprange(value,min1,max1,min2,max2){
          return((value-min1)*(max2-min2))/(max1-min1)+min2;
        }
         
        </script>
       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share your client-side code as well? that's most likely where the problem manifested

Comment: I added  Client-side Code please let me know if you know what the Problem is

Comment: I tried to run the exact same code on my machine but I didn't see such behaviour. However, I noticed a ./haptics.js file, could you share this file as well?

Comment: I am using an API to get the elevtion Value here is the link: https://www.opentopodata.org/ and the haptic.js it was a A library for enabling haptic effects but I don't used anymore because now I'am using real vibration Motor

Comment: @HarryHsu and you have to name the HTML Page `index` to get that working because of this Line  `var index = fs.readFileSync( 'index.html');` in the Server.

Comment: I had the local server setup and I provided some stub data for the elevation API, i was able to see the elevation data being written to CSV but I don't see such browser refreshing issue

Comment: @HarryHsu can you please try to move the slider ? then you will see the Problem